# How to check Methods return type in ArchUnit c#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, archunit

I need to check that there is only one class method ("ExampleMethod") that returns "ExampleType". Can I do this with ArchUnit in C #?

Comment: C# is a statically-typed language, so such a test is completely unnecessary (and of course, you can have the compiler enforce return-types with an `interface` or `delegate`).

Comment: ...or do you mean that you have a `virtual` method that has a static return type of some base-class and you want a test to assert the _actual_ return type is a specific subclass?

Comment: What do you mean by "class method"? Do you mean a `static` method as opposed to an instance method?

Comment: I have a lot of Methods in Class, and I need to be sure that only one(created by me "ExampleMethod") returns "ExampleType". In future when someone else create methods, I`ve  got an error that someone cannot create method with return type "ExampleMethod"

Comment: Class method It's just a method

Comment: I'm not familiar with ArchUnit-for-C#, but I see it works by analyzing the output assembly's bytecode - that seems overkill: you can do this with _any_ unit-testing framework (e.g. xUnit, MSTest, etc) and Reflection.

Comment: How can I get all methods from class?

Comment: See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use ArchUnit - or anything really, just use .NET's built-in reflection API:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

#if !( XUNIT || MSTEST || NUNIT)
    #error "Specify unit testing framework"
#endif

#if MSTEST
[TestClass]
#elif NUNIT
[TestFixture]
#endif
public class ReflectionTests
{
#if XUNIT
    [Fact]
#elif MSTEST
    [TestMethod]
#elif NUNIT
    [Test]
#endif
    public void MyClass_should_have_only_1_ExampleMethod()
    {
        const BindingFlags BF = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;

        MethodInfo mi = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods( BF ).Single( m => m.Name == "ExampleMethod" );

#if XUNIT
        Assert.Equal( expected: typeof(ExampleType), actual: mi.ReturnType );
#elif MSTEST || NUNIT
        Assert.AreEqual( expected: typeof(ExampleType), actual: mi.ReturnType );
#endif
    }
}
```